# TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined - React-typeahead

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, typeahead, reactstrap

I'm using `react-bootstrap-typeahead` component to predict user input into text box, but I am having trouble setting the state so user can click on a selection in the dropdown menu.[here](https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead)

So far code I have is here. The function `handleAddtask` adds task to tasklist when typed in, but I cannot get it to assign to typeahead dropdown. (I am still learning react so any resources on this would also be appreciated).

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Typeahead } from "react-bootstrap-typeahead";

class AddWatchlistForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      taskName: ""
    };
    this.handleAddTask = this.handleAddTask.bind(this);
  }

  static propTypes = {
    newTask: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
          <div style={{ margin: "20px" }}>
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-6">
                <Typeahead
                  placeholder=""
                  onChange={e => this.updateTaskName(e)}
                  onClick={(e => this.updateTask(e), this.handleAddTask)}
                  value={this.state.taskName}
                  onKeyPress={e => this.checkEnterKey(e)}
                  labelKey={option =>
                    `${option.ticker} ${option.security_type}`
                  }
                  options={[
                    {
                      "": 0,
                      ticker: "A",
                      security_type: "Stock"
                    },
                    {
                      "": 1,
                      ticker: "AA",
                      security_type: "Stock"
                    },
                    {
                      "": 2,
                      ticker: "AAA",
                      security_type: "Stock"
                    },
                    {
                      "": 3,
                      ticker: "AAAU",
                      security_type: "Stock"
                    },
                    {
                      "": 4,
                      ticker: "AACG",
                      security_type: "Stock"
                    }
                  ]}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-4">
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="btn btn-primary"
                  onClick={this.handleAddTask}
                >
                  {" "}
                  Add New...{" "}
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  checkEnterKey(e) {
    var keyCode = e.which || e.keyCode;
    if (keyCode == 13) {
      if (this.state.taskName.trim() !== "") {
        this.props.newTask(this.state.taskName);
      }
    }
  }

  updateTaskName(e) {
    this.setState({ taskName: e.target.value });
  }

  updateTask(e) {
    this.setState({ taskName: e.target.options.ticker });
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  handleAddTask(e) {
    let name = e.target.value;
    if (this.state.taskName.trim() !== "")
      this.props.newTask(this.state.taskName);
  }
}
export default AddWatchlistForm;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestion, a better way of doing things using Arrow Functions preserving the context of `this`:

Remove the following...

```js
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      taskName: ""
    };
    this.handleAddTask = this.handleAddTask.bind(this);
  }

  handleAddTask(e) {
    let name = e.target.value;
    if (this.state.taskName.trim() !== "")
      this.props.newTask(this.state.taskName);
  }
```

And add this instead:

```js
  state = {
    taskName: ""
  };

  handleAddTask = e => {
    let name = e.target.value;
    if (this.state.taskName.trim() !== "")
      this.props.newTask(this.state.taskName);
  }
```

And the reason why you get the `TypeError` due to `undefined` is the same reason. I just tried by replacing all the normal functions to arrow functions and they all worked fine now. Else you should be binding to `this` for every single class property function, which is a tedious double process and performance intensive.

Also, in the `handleAddTask` function, please update:

```js
  handleAddTask = e => {
    let name = e.target.value;
    if (this.state.taskName.trim() !== "")
      this.props.newTask(name);
  };
```

**Solution**

The problem is with the `e` that gets passed to. Change your `updateTaskName` function to:

```js
  updateTaskName = e => {
    this.setState({ taskName: e.length > 0 ? e[0].security_type : "" });
  };
```

This is because, `e` is:

```js
e = {
  "": 2,
  ticker: "AAA",
  security_type: "Stock"
};
```

**Working Demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-moore-wsq5p

Comment: This worked perfect! the enter key stopped working to submit, but I think I can figure that part out.

Comment: @JasonMaynard `console.log()` is your friend (not Google). He he. Glad it helped you.